# Javascript function not getting called. Firebug shows reference error

Tags: javascript

I am writing a form and trying to call a javascript function

```
    <form onSubmit="$('<%$containerName%>').update(''); submitForReinstate(this, $('<%$containerName%>')); return false;">
```

but when I run this, FireBug shows  "ReferenceError: submitForReinstate is not defined". But this function is defined in some other file. Do I need to link both the files in some manner?

Can anyone please give me a pointer as to how to solve this?

I searched thoroughly on google but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Did you included the submitForReinstate function contained file in your  calling file ?

Comment: Either the file that defines the function is not included, you typoed the function name, or the function definition is out of scope (is it inside a document ready event for example)?

Comment: submitForReinstate is defined in a mason file in which function is enclosed in <script> tags. and from where i am calling this function is also a mason file.

Comment: If Mason refers to the Perl "High-performance, dynamic web site authoring system" referenced at https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-Mason you'll get better answers by mentioning that in your question.

Comment: I got my mistake. There was a syntax error in some other function due to which no function was loading.

Answer (score 0):

> *"But this function is defined in some other file. Do I need to link both the files in some manner?"*

Yes. Assuming the first file contains html, which yours seems to given the `<form>` element you show, you include a reference to the second file within the first. The second file would need to contain just JavaScript (no `<script>` tags), and then in the main file add this:

```
<script src="nameofotherfile.js"></script>
```

If the file isn't in the same directory include an appropriate path in the `src` attribute.

The two most common places to add `<script>` elements are within the `<head>` section or just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: the file in which this function is defined is a mason file and the fnction is enclosed whithin <script type="text/javascript"> </script>. Do i need to include script src=" " now also?

Comment: I don't know what a mason file is. At a guess I'd say what you need is a server-side include, so not a script element with src.